# Adding a link to HTML button on WordPress Astra Theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I posted the same question earlier today that was closed but the problem I have has not been resolved.

Problem:

I am trying to add a link to a HTML main menu button on a WordPress Astra theme. If I use the following code the button is displayed with the correct formatting but does not link to the page I need it to:

```
<button class="wpmem_loginout" >Sign-In</button<>
```

If I use the suggested code that was provided in my last post:

```
<a href="/sign-in" class="wpmem_loginout">Sign-In</a>
```

The formatting of the button is removed but the link works as it should. I have included a picture of what I mean when I say formatting. The section on the left is with the format removed and the section on the right displays the button as it should look (Red with white text).

Does anyone have any further suggestions? I have also tried to use the suggested code and add CSS after to format the button properly. But that did not work either...

Thanks,
Guy[image: Astra menu bar]

Comment: You can add that as a menu item instead and then the link will always be correct (making sure not to set it as a custom html link but choosing it from the Pages list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `button` for you is not working because it has no functionality associated with it. Just `add onclick function` and change the location href to your required url. It will work fine.

```html
<button class="wpmem_loginout" onclick="window.location.href='/sign-in'">Sign-In</button<>
```

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.

Comment: Worked a treat - Thanks!